# Java sockets, sending data to and from?

Tags: java, sockets, io

Alright, I'm trying to set a program I have to receive data from a socket, and send data to a socket. I'm stumped on how to get the client side of the socket to send specific data, then have the server side send specific data. Here's what I currently have, it's only my server-side because I'm really lost on the client part as of now.

To further evaluate, I would like to do as listed in the following, yet I can't figure out what to research to write the client-side of the socket, and if there was any code I would need to rewrite in the server side?
[image: To further evaluate]

```
package sockets;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SocketMain {
    private int port = 0;
    public ServerSocket socket;
    public Socket clientSock;

    public SocketMain() {
        init();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SocketMain();
    }

    private void init() {
        try { 
            socket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server started, bound to port: "+port);
            clientSock = socket.accept();
            File directory = new File("./Storage/");
            if (!directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(directory + "/Store.dat");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSock.getInputStream());  
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                bw.write(line+"\n");
                bw.flush();
                bw.close();
            }
            socket.close();
            clientSock.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you catching the IOException?

Comment: Do you have a particular problem?  Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry, I was adding an image to help explain what I needed to do, I'm curious as to how I can specify the data on the client side for the server to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**About what you currently have:**

The first thing that jumped in my eye was this loop:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    bw.write(line+"\n");
    bw.flush();
    bw.close(); // <- Problem
}
```

You're closing the writer every time you write a line. Now, as the documentation of [`Writer.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#close%28%29) states:

> Closes the stream, flushing it first. **Once the stream has been
>   closed, further write() or flush() invocations will cause an
>   IOException to be thrown.** Closing a previously closed stream has no
>   effect.

You should be getting `IOException`s for every line after the first one. You program will however not crash, since you're catching the exceptions.

---

Second, you use `DataInputStream` to read from your client, but write out using a `BufferedWriter`. As the former states in [it's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html):

> A data input stream lets an application **read primitive Java data types
>   from an underlying input stream** in a machine-independent way. An
>   application uses a data output stream to write data that can later be
>   read by a data input stream.

The class includes multiple methods for boolean, char, int, whatever primitive data-type you can think of. But for the [`DataInputStream.readLine()`-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29), it clearly states:

> **Deprecated**. **This method does not properly convert bytes to characters.**
>   As of JDK 1.1, **the preferred way to read lines of text is via the
>   `BufferedReader.readLine()` method.**

So, for reading strings, you should use a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

---

**About what you don't yet have:**

The communication over sockets is established on a "ask-answer" base. The workflow should be something like this:

1. Client opens connection
2. Server accepts connection
3. Client asks for something (using the server-sockets `OutputStream`)
4. Server reads the request (using the client-sockets `InputStream`)
5. Server answers (using the client-sockets `OutputStream`)
6. Client reads the answer (using the server-sockets `InputStream`)
7. Repeat steps 3-6 if necessary.
8. Connection is closed (either by client, server or both).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code besides:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSock.getInputStream());  
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
```

[`DataInputStream.getLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29) is deprecated -- you should just use [`BufferedReader.getLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29):

> Programs that use the DataInputStream class to read lines can be converted to use the BufferedReader class by replacing code of the form:
>
> ```
> DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(in);
> ```
>
> with:
>
> ```
> BufferedReader d  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
> ```